# How to transfer file from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, attachment, files

Does anyone know how to do that?

When in SF creates opportunity with some attached files (PDFs) - need to send an email from Marketing Cloud with some opp info and attached to this email files that were attached to that opp.
So how can I transfer immediately files from SF to MC and then attach them to email message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [AttachFile](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/) AMPscript function to attach a file to an email:

> This function attaches the specified file to the outbound message or
> displays a link to the file when included in a landing page. This
> function returns no output.

Regarding “transferring” the file from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud, it’s a redundancy you don’t need - instead, generate a url for each pdf directly in Salesforce and synch the Opportunity object to Marketing Cloud. That way you will be able to attach the file directly from Salesforce without transferring it anywhere and creating duplicates in both clouds.

Here’s an example of a similar use case from the ampscript.guide:

```
%%[

var @fileName, @fileAlias
set @fileName = "https://limedash.com/drop/LoyaltyMembers.zip"
set @fileAlias = "LoyaltyMembers.zip"

AttachFile("HTTP", @fileName, @fileAlias)

]%%
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you!